# Socket.io (emit, on) not working - Node JS

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am working on a node JS application, where I am trying to use socket.io following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNqVpESuyQo&index=4&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9i4V-_ZVwLmOusj8YAUhj_9) tutorial. Until this tutorial everything is fine, even the client is connected to the server through the socket, as it display a message on connection. But I don't know why my code isn't working on emit, and on event, and event handler.

Below is my Code on server side :

```js
const express              =    require("express");
const app                  =    express();
const scrap                =    require("./algorithm");
const mysql                =    require("mysql");
const ms_connect           =    mysql.createConnection({
                                    host:'localhost',
                                    user:'root',
                                    password:'',
                                    database:'scrapper_db'
                                });
const server = app.listen(8000, function(){ console.log('Listening on 8000'); });
const io                   =    require("socket.io").listen(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));


io.on("connection",function(socket){
    console.log("Sockets Connection Made ! " + socket.id);
    socket.emit("testing",{data:"I am tested"});
    io.on("disconnect",function(){
        console.log("Client Disconnected !");
    })
})

//mySQL Conection
ms_connect.connect(function(err){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    
    ms_connect.query("Select * FROM test",function(err,rows,fields){
        if(err) console.log("Error Executing Query");
    })

})

app.get("/scrap",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
})
```

Client side code :

```js
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000/scrap');
console.log(socket.connected); //returns false :(
socket.on("testing", function(d) {
  console.log(d);
});
```

> In the client side, the `socket.connected` object returns `false`, but on server side it says connected. I don't know how , and 
>   I am using third link from [this](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io/2.1.1) socket.io cdnjs server.

Comment: Why are you putting scrap on the client side? http://localhost:8000/scrap

Comment: This is the route for loading my index.html file from `app.get("/scrap",func)` @RaphaelFacredyn

Comment: You should try using  `socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log(socket.connected); // true
});` rather than just logging `socket.connected`

Also what happens if you just use `var socket = io.connect();` on your client side code

Comment: Should i use this on client side @TommyBs ?

Comment: @Nadeem Ahmad yes

Comment: yes, you should put it on the client side

Comment: Perfecto ! Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `io.connect('http://localhost:8000/scrap')` but the scrap is not mentioned anywhere on the server side. It should be `io.connect('http://localhost:8000/')`. Pointing to your HTML file is not needed because the socket.io server and your webserver are unrelated.

Also as pointed out by @TommyBs you should use

```
socket.on('connect', () => { console.log(socket.connected);  });
```

to check if you are connected because connecting is asynchronous so it will not have connected yet by the time you do `console.log(socket.connected);`

The whole client code would be

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
socket.on('connect', () => { console.log(socket.connected);  });
socket.on("testing", function(d) {
  console.log(d);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `http://localhost:8000/scrap` to `http://localhost:8000/` in the client code. You're connecting to the wrong route.